# Angular setTimeout() with external lambda with parameter

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to solve two problems simultaneously: 1) use `setTimeout( #action#, timeMillis)` with #action# as lambda 2) supply lambda with a parameter.

A popular approach with `setTimeout( ()=>{ #callback# }, timeMillis)` works perfectly when I extract `()=>{ #callback# }` to lambda (and this case lambda has no parameters).
 But if I try to pass a lambda with parameter to setTimeout - this function stops working properly - callback fires immediately.

Here  is my code:

```
let lambda = (text: string) : TimerHandler => {
    alert(text)
    return ""
}

 .  .  .  .

lambda('text1')                     // value passes to lambda (show 'text1')         - OK  |  no delay - X
setTimeout(lambda, 3000);           // value don't pass to lambda (show 'undefined') - X   |  delay    - OK
setTimeout(lambda('text3'), 3000);  // value passes to lambda (show 'text1')         - OK  |  no delay - X
```

Note: Accordingly to setTimeout docs, first #action# parameter is of type [TimerHandler](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7cf6c70d90b60e962db417d80290288eb786b5fd/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L18739), and this type is extension of [string](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7cf6c70d90b60e962db417d80290288eb786b5fd/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L19984). Thats why I have to return "empty_string" inside lambda's body.

Maybe this behaviour occurs because of an empty string in return statement? But I don't know what to set there

Comment: What's timerhandler?

Answer (score 2):

You can use setTimeout function properly this way:

```
const lambda = (text: string) : TimerHandler => {
  console.info(text);
  return '';
}

setTimeout(lambda, 3000, "hola");
```

Output after 3 secs

```
"hola"
```

setTimeout receive args after the third prop.

The syntax is:

```
let timerId = setTimeout(func|code, [delay], [arg1], [arg2], ...)
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The call `setTimeout(lambda('text3'), 3000);` fires immediately because the function is called and it's return value is scheduled with the timeout.

Either pass parameters as described in @bjdose's answer, or use the callback form `setTimeout(() => { this.lambda('text4') }, 3000);`.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eyx7vn)